# Using a WP shortcode in Homepage

Tags: shortcode

my WP blog is just a part of my homepage/serverspace. I would like to know if it's possible to use a WP shortcode outside of the WP folder, meaning, not inside of the WP template but in another html file on my server?

Please excuse my bad english & thank you for your time.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: You could e.g. set up an admin-ajax endpoint to render the shortcode and have your other page call this to get HTML to include in itself. (And you ought to cache the returned HTML rather than requesting it every time.) But you'd probably also need to include some style sheets and maybe some script from your WordPress too. It might be simpler to reimplement the shortcode in your separate site using data fetched from WordPress some other way e.g. over the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. It is advisable, if possible, to power the whole site with WordPress, you could turn the said html file into a WordPress template.